# Write to static field from instance method

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have my code as below. I see

```
public MyClass{

    private static DataSource dataSource = null;

    private static DataSource getDataSource(){
        if (dataSource == null) {
            try {
                dataSource = // something.
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // some exception.
            }
        }

        return dataSource;
    }

    public List doSomething(){

        // ...

        if(dataSource == null){
            dataSource = getDataSource();
        }

        dataSource.getConnection();
        // ...

    }
}
```

I see following message in sonar anaylsis.

```
Dodgy - Write to static field from instance method

This instance method writes to a static field. This is tricky to get correct if multiple instances are being manipulated, and generally bad practice.
findbugs:ST_WRITE_TO_STATIC_FROM_INSTANCE_METHOD Sep12 Reliability > Architecture
```

I see everything is okay in this implementation except that we are changing the static variable in doSomething method. How do we fix this ?

Comment: Do the assignment in the static method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure how your static analysis tool works but -

try writing to your value via a static setter:

```
private synchronized static void setDataSource(DataSource ds) {
    dataSource = ds;
}
```

so that you can do

```
   if(dataSource == null){
        setDataSource(getDataSource());
   }
```

Comment: I think this post marked as answer would be complete only if there is a null check for datasource again in the static setter. Else, it's still not thread safe.

Answer (score 2):

You have to choose between two solutions , first one is in your Datasource class add `getDatasource()` method and  synchronize the block where you instantiate your static field :

```
    private static DataSource getDataSource(){
     synchronize(DataSource.class){
            if (dataSource == null) {
                try {
                    dataSource = // something.
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // some exception.
                }
            }
       }
        return dataSource;
      }
```

then you will just call this method from your `doSomething()` method

```
public void doSomething(){
//
DataSource dataSource=DataSource.getDataSource();
//
}
```

second solution is to instantiate your field at the class loading time using a static block or directly from the declaration.

```
static {
 dataSource = // something.
}
```