# How to fix, static field from instance method in Find Bugs?

Tags: java, android, findbugs

The code below I have issue,
I have more than one class, in example2 class have static boolean `var`

```
public class example2 extends Activity {
    public static boolean var = false;
}
```

In example1 have static variable reference from example2.

```
public class example1 extends Activity {

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        example2.var = false;
    }
}
```

> Bug: Write to static field com.example.example2.fromVar from instance method com.example.example2.onResume()

How to resolve this one...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities.  Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24703755/write-to-static-field-from-instance-method, which explains why findbugs thinks this is a bad practice.  Since you're working with Android, though, I think you need an Android-specific solution.

Comment: Use shared preferences to save values.

Comment: actually the description of the bug has nothing to do with example1, you probably do the writing in one of the example2 methods. in example2.onResume() apparently

Answer (score 0):

Well, writing to a static field from a non-static context is a code-smell, Why you do it this way?
Fix is simple, don't write to a static variable, but it is hard to help when we don't see all of your code.